# This page isn't working. www.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500. PHP Laravel OVH

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, http-status-code-500, ovh

I'am facing the Http 500 error on a laravel 5.1 deployed on an OVH mutualized hosting plan. I waned to debug and display the error but I always get the same display message. I've tried to set display_errors = on in php.ini and in laravel server.php. who can help me please in this situation. I need to display the error.

Comment: Are you sure the permissions on the resources/logs folder are correct? This can cause 500 errors and not show log in folder. You should be able to see something if you turn on debug in the .env

Comment: I have managed to fix the error by getting the bootstrap folder from another laravel project as it was missing for some reason. That's why I want to know if possible how the prossess of installing laravel dependencies (vendor) works on a shared host as I don't execute composer install manually. Thank you